# Long time delay callback in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, settimeout, job-scheduling

I want to set a delay of 24 hours in online server glitch for Facebook messenger bot. I need send message after every 24 hours in NodeJs for sending messages in Facebook bot page. I tired `cron` job, schedule job and `settimeout` but none of these work on my case. I need help in NodeJs. A server code which run after every 24 hours and send message to user on specific string.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/delay this npm module can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a Cron job that will run every day(I am giving the example that will run every day at 12:00 AM). I prefer you can use [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) module

The below is the code to run crone job every day 12 AM.

```
var job = new CronJob('0 0 0 * * *', function() {
 //will run every day at 12:00 AM
})
```

For more information about Cron [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

Comment: Cron job not working for me. I implemented for 10 mins for my checking but not working.

Comment: It would be great if you can share your Cron job code.